# Html content is not showed in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create an http server. The server is created correctly but does NOT show the html content. It works when I do it without listeners. What am I failing then?

*app.js*

```
var server = require("./server.js");

   server.server3((req, res, html) => {
   res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
   html.pipe(res);
   res.end();
 }, 3000, "./index.html");
```

*server.js*

```
    function Server3(applyFunction, port, path) {
var fs = require("fs"),
    html = fs.createReadStream(path.toString().trim()), // Create stream from path
    http = require("http");

    html.on("data", _ => {}) 
        .on("end", () => { // create server when all data is ready
        http.createServer(function(req, res){ // createServer method
        applyFunction(req, res, html); // execute the function
        }).listen(+port); // add the port
        });

}
module.exports.server3 = Server3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to create an HTTP server on node.js, using the express framework (`npm install express --save`) would simplify your life a great deal.  If you place the `index.html` file in the same directory as `app.js`, you can create the server with the following 5 lines of code:

```
  // Setup Express
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();

  // Use main directory to find HTML file
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));

  // Render index.html
  app.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("index"));

  // Start Server on port 3000
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started on port 3000'));
```

Comment: i know how to create server, I need the reason, why I fail